# Angle of bones required during animation play

Tags: python, rigging

I have made a dog rigging example by following some tutorial on youtube. I want to know is there any way i can get angles of any bone live at each frame. I need to export these angles in a file.
Please help.
[image]

I did the rigging, now I am trying to get bone angle on runtime during animation. I did this.

```py
import bpy
from math import degrees
from bpy import context

arm = context.object

print(arm.pose.bones["Bone.002"].rotation_axis_angle[1])
```

but this is only printing the angle which was set initially.
Can somebody help pls?